# Выставка фотографов, или Выставка фотографий?

Tags: грамматика, узус, фраза

Наткнулся на фразу "**Выставка фотографов**". Это вообще правильно? Так можно сказать, когда речь идёт о "Выставке работ фотографов"?

Если так можно сказать, то почему? Ведь фраза меняет свой смысл. И как тогда сказать о выставке, на которой будут выставлены сами фотографы?

И даже, если так можно сказать, то грамотно ли это?

Comment: да, вообще это правильно

Answer (score 7):

Выставка фотографов — это выставка, на которой представлены фотографии определенных фотографов. Это выражение используется с каким-нибудь определением (например "выставка молодых фотографов" или "выставка английских фотографов"). Так же как говорят "выставка художников" (опять же, обычно с определением). Имеется в виду, что фотографии на выставке выбраны исходя из того кем они сделаны, в отличие от выставки фотографий (природы например, или жанровых фотографий), где выбор делается исходя из темы снимка.

Выражение "выставка фотографов" можно сравнить с выражением "выставка художников". Конечно, чисто технически, можно решить что это выставка, экспонатами которой являются художники. Но неоднозначности подобного рода встречаются в любом языке, и подобная неоднозначность не обязательно означает что так говорить неправильно.

["Выставка художников" в поиске корпуса русского языка](http://search2.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%E2%FB%F1%F2%E0%E2%EA%E0%20%F5%F3%E4%EE%E6%ED%E8%EA%EE%E2) дает 14 вхождений

["Выставка (?) художников" там же](http://search2.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&spd=&text=lexgramm&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&parent1=0&level1=0&lex1=%E2%FB%F1%F2%E0%E2%EA%E0&gramm1=&sem1=&sem-mod1=sem&sem-mod1=sem2&flags1=&m1=&parent2=0&level2=0&min2=1&max2=2&lex2=%F5%F3%E4%EE%E6%ED%E8%EA&gramm2=&sem2=&sem-mod2=sem&sem-mod2=sem2&flags2=&m2=) — 278 вхождений

["Выставка произведений (?) художников"](http://search2.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=sas1_2&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&dpp=100&spp=100&spd=100&text=lexgramm&mode=ngrams_3_lexgr&sort=gr_freq&lang=ru&nodia=1&parent1=0&level1=0&lex1=%E2%FB%F1%F2%E0%E2%EA%E0&gramm1=&flags1=&parent2=0&level2=0&min2=1&max2=1&lex2=%EF%F0%EE%E8%E7%E2%E5%E4%E5%ED%E8%E9&gramm2=&flags2=&parent3=0&level3=0&min3=1&max3=3&lex3=%F5%F3%E4%EE%E6%ED%E8%EA%EE%E2&gramm3=&flags3=) — 0

["Выставка работ (?) художников"](http://search2.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=sas1_2&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&dpp=100&spp=100&spd=100&text=lexgramm&mode=ngrams_3_lexgr&sort=gr_freq&lang=ru&nodia=1&parent1=0&level1=0&lex1=%E2%FB%F1%F2%E0%E2%EA%E0&gramm1=&flags1=&parent2=0&level2=0&min2=1&max2=1&lex2=%F0%E0%E1%EE%F2&gramm2=&flags2=&parent3=0&level3=0&min3=1&max3=2&lex3=%F5%F3%E4%EE%E6%ED%E8%EA%EE%E2&gramm3=&flags3=) — 0

["Выставка картин (?) художников"](http://search2.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=sas1_2&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&dpp=100&spp=100&spd=100&text=lexgramm&mode=ngrams_3_lexgr&sort=gr_freq&lang=ru&nodia=1&parent1=0&level1=0&lex1=%E2%FB%F1%F2%E0%E2%EA%E0&gramm1=&flags1=&parent2=0&level2=0&min2=1&max2=1&lex2=%EA%E0%F0%F2%E8%ED&gramm2=&flags2=&parent3=0&level3=0&min3=1&max3=2&lex3=%F5%F3%E4%EE%E6%ED%E8%EA%EE%E2&gramm3=&flags3=) — 0

Comment: Что, теоретически мешает выставить фотографов в клетках?

Comment: _Не вполне понятно что такое "выставка на которой будут выставлены сами фотографы"_ - выставка, на которой экспонатами являются сами фотографы (ср. выставка собак).

Answer (score 2):

Выставка фотографов - это выставка, экспонатами на которой являются фотографы.  Например, фотографы сидят в клетках, а посетители их рассматривают.  Если же экспонатами являются фотографии, то это выставка фотографий.

"Выставка молодых фотографов" - тоже неправильно. Правильно "выставка работ молодых фотографов".

Корпус русского языка находит в общей сложности 21 документ с выражением "выставка фотографий" (во всех падежах и обоих числах), но ни одного вхождения выражения "выставка фотографов".

Comment: Корпус не находит и "выставка работ фотографов" а вот "выставка художников" — 14 вхождений при чем если поставить дистанцию от 1 до 2, то больше двухсот.

Comment: Никита Алексеев. Догоним Португалию // Известия, 2007.12.24   
Первая масштабная выставка фотографов Magnum в Манеже Музей Московский дом фотографии закрылся на реконструкцию, но открывает начавшийся сезон выставкой в недавно восстановленном Манеже. [Никита Алексеев. Догоним Португалию // Известия, 2007.12.24] [омонимия не снята] ←…→
А столь масштабная выставка фотографов Magnum―первая в Москве. [Никита Алексеев. Догоним Португалию //

Comment: "Выставка работ фотографов" - с одной стороны корректно, а с другой - длинно и бюрократизм. Язык всё-таки силён контекстом

Comment: Ну что значит правильно или неправильно - если по факту есть словоупотребление то как можно говорить о его неправильности?

Answer (score 1):

"Выставка фотографов"  — это сокращение от "Выставка работ фотографов". Слово "работ" можно выкинуть без потери информативности (выставка чего еще может быть?)

"Выставка работ фотографов" — это [плеоназм](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC), стилистическая ошибка.

Comment: Может быть "Выставка черепов фотографов", "Выставка жён фотографов", "Выставка квартир фотографов", "Выставка фотоаппаратов фотографов"... Да чего угодно! Едва ли это можно назвать плеоназмом.

Answer (score 0):

И как тогда сказать о выставке, на которой будут выставлены сами фотографы?
Though the phrase is ambiguous, it is implied that photographers bring their art to gallery for exhibition, thus you'll have to explain if you talk about exhibition where the artists themselves are incarcerated.